# Unique count everyday

Tags: r

I would like to know if Customer Ben received unique Item 1 everyday? Catch here is item 1 is unique everyday, but item 2 or 3 are not. It is possible that a customer may have received two items1 in a day and not any in another day - so the formula need to correctly identify that customer received at least one unique item1 a day. I would like to know how I can create a variable that tags that Ben received unique item1 everyday.

[image]

```
structure(list(Customer = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Ben", class = "factor"), 
    Date = structure(c(1L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
    14L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("1/1/2016", "1/10/2016", 
    "1/11/2016", "1/12/2016", "1/13/2016", "1/14/2016", "1/2/2016", 
    "1/3/2016", "1/4/2016", "1/5/2016", "1/6/2016", "1/7/2016", 
    "1/8/2016", "1/9/2016"), class = "factor"), Item1 = structure(c(1L, 
    7L, 1L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L), .Label = c("A1", "A10", "A11", "A12", "A13", "A14", 
    "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8", "A9"), class = "factor"), 
    Item2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", 
    "B6", "B7", "B8"), class = "factor"), Item3 = structure(c(1L, 
    7L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L), .Label = c("A1", "A10", "A11", "A12", "A13", "A14", 
    "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8", "A9"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Customer", 
"Date", "Item1", "Item2", "Item3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))

length(unique(x$Date)) == length(unique(x$Item1))
length(unique(x$Date)) == length(unique(x$Item2))
length(unique(x$Date)) == length(unique(x$Item3))
```

I edited the data to show the dilemma. I want to tag that Ben received at least one unique item1 everyday. item3 is slightly different and it is not different everyday.

Working solution (credit goes to @alistaire):

```
df$distinct1 <- sapply(seq_along(df$Item1), function(x){!df[x, 'Item1'] %in% df[0:(x-1), 'Item1']})
length(unique(df$Date))==length(unique(df$Date[df$distinct1==TRUE]))

df$distinct3 <- sapply(seq_along(df$Item3), function(x){!df[x, 'Item3'] %in% df[0:(x-1), 'Item3']})
length(unique(df$Date))==length(unique(df$Date[df$distinct3==TRUE]))
```

Comment: What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: To build a column with a value for whether there is a unique value for `Item1` on that day: `library(dplyr) ; df %>% group_by(Date) %>% mutate(distinct1 = any(mapply(function(x, y){!x %in% df[df$Date != y, 'Item1']}, Item1, Date)))`